# mobotix camera using curl

Tags: c++, curl, openssl, libcurl, ip-camera

I have [mobotix camera sdk 1.02](http://developer.mobotix.com/zips/mobotix_sdk_1.0.2.zip)(latest version), and using it with curl libraries. In this sdk 1.02, a example code, mxgconv, is given which performs File IO and gives the output. now I'm facing problem while using 
"curl [url of camera] | mxgconv >another_test.mjpg". 
I understand that, here by using curl we are getting the live stream from camera and the command above is piping output of curl to mxgconv, which is redirecting it to file. But I'm getting image size as 0kb.

Comment: no code, no environment, no actual input, so expected output, and where is the posted line being run, (what OS, is this a command line on the terminal, is the camera currently trying to record a movie or is the request for a previously recorded movie, etc.) How do you expect us to debug the problem?

Comment: the link to the camera info is ok, but the links at that URL are incorrectly written as they reference the local computer (mine) rather than the company computer

Comment: according to the scant information available about the camera operation, the `curl` statement needs to pass certain 'GET' info to the camera.  The posted line fails to pass anything to the camera.

Comment: all the software for the camera API is written in C++ so this is not a C question,  please remove the `c` tag

Comment: OS is windows 7 32bit, the link which i have given is for the download of sdk in which the example code is given.

Comment: the command <br/> "curl [url of camera] | mxgconv >another_test.mjpg" <br/> is specific to that camera, for example i use 192.168.1.49.

Comment: I got my problem solved, thanks!!!!

Comment: what did you do to fix the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the parameter of (output file) of mxgconv in order to store in a file all frames he is converting. 
You shall use this command line:

"curl [url of camera] | mxgconv of=another_test.mjpg, separator=END_OF_FRAME"